# jQuery/Javascript - From an Email link to pop open a specific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what i am trying to achieve is this

the user will get an email with a link

http://sitess.com/someother_stuff

once they click that link from the email it will take them to the homepage of the site where there are links...when you click the link a popup appears

but i want the popup to trigger once the user clicks the link on the email and takes them to the site.

heres a snippet of the link i am working on

```
<div id="sidebar-active-searches" style="padding: 5px 20px; line-height: 120%; height: 660px;">
  <a class="thickbox" title="JEWISH FEDERATION OF GREATER LOS ANGELES – VP of STRATEGIC PHILANTHROPY" href="/active-searches-items/jewish-federation-of-greater-los-angeles-vp-of-strategic-philanthropy/?TB_iframe">
  <strong>Jewish Federation of <br />Greater Los Angeles</strong> 
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-556" alt="&gt;&gt;"  src="http://www.moppenheim.com/wp-content/uploads/red-arrow.gif" width="9" height="7" />
  <br /> 
    Vice President of Strategic Philanthropy
  </a>
</div>
```

ive had something like this before but it is not working

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  // find hash from parent. if it exists, trigger a click on one of the items above. 
  // the hash must match the id of the item.
  var hash = parent.window.location.hash;

  // split the query string apart from the hash  - this expect the hash to be first!
  var hash_array = hash.split("&");

  // make sure the first array element starts with a '#' mark, otherwise, it is probably   just the query string.  
  if(hash_array[0].indexOf('#')>=0)
    {
      $(hash_array[0]).trigger('click');
    }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your hyperlink

```
http://sitess.com/someother_stuff?LinkToPopup=ExampleLinkID
```

In your homepage (to detect if there is a passed item:

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var urlPassedParameters = getUrlVars();

if (urlPassedParameters['LinkToPopup'] != null) {
            var linkToPopup = decodeURI(urlPassedParameters['LinkToPopup']);
            $(linkToPopup).click()
        }
```

Comment: @user1502223 ExampleLinkId is the ID of the link you will be calling on the home page, you can pass the whole url if you want and then do a search by that the framework is the same.

Comment: i get an error in my console Uncaught ReferenceError: urlPassedParameters is not defined how should urlPassedParamaters be defined?